# Filter facebook graph results by any given field

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I was wondering if it's possible to somehow filter graph results by any given field.

For example (Marketing API request through the graph API)

```
/{adaccount_id}/users?user={given user id}
```

Today i have to fetch all users and then in my code i have to filter out all other users that don't match. This makes it (counting as a data structure guy) very inefficient since in many requests i have to do huge breakdowns, which costs a lot of resources (some of them up to and over O(N^3)).

Any given help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering if it's possible to somehow filter graph results by any given field.

No.

Some endpoints have specific extra parameters for filtering – but there’s only a few. But you can not filter by just any arbitrary fields.

> This makes it (counting as a data structure guy) very inefficient

From discussions I had about this with Facebook developers, they say it would affect overall API performance badly – so they rather let apps do any advanced filtering on their end.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this information was helpful! <3

Comment: The hell! how is this better than FQL that they have discontinued. I rather only import events in the future not the 1000s of events in the past and filter for it. affects my overall API performance badly. Please confirm?